# Javascript - comparing if 2 objects are the same

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects that will always have the same amount of properties just in occasion the values may be different.

I am attempting to do a check against the 2 objects to see if they are the same value

I decided to try and handle this using the `.every` method but all results are returning `false` even when I am expecting it to be true.

How can I compare 2 objects to see they are equal?

Here is a code snippet

```js
const priceOne = {
"price": 14.31,
"taxes": 2.00,
"total": 16.31
}

const priceTwo = {
"price": 14.31,
"taxes": 2.00,
"total": 16.31
}

const comparePrice = Object.keys(priceOne).every((item, index) => {
      item === Object.keys(priceTwo)[index] ?  true :  false
    })
    
console.log(comparePrice)
```

Comment: Already answered here [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: Do you expect `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` and `{ b: 2, a: 1 }` to be equal?

Comment: @jabaa I expect both objects being compared to have the same order

Comment: That means `{ "price": 14.31, "taxes": 2.00, "total": 16.31 }` and `{ "price": 14.31, "total": 16.31, "taxes": 2.00 }` are different? I'm not sure you, can achieve this running on engines before ES5. AFAIK, the property is defined since ES5.

Comment: @jabaa my apologies, I don't follow. I expect them to be in the same order so price, taxes, total comparing to prices, taxes,  total. The key order would remain the same but sometimes the content will be different. Example `"price": 14.31` vs `"price": 12.00` etc

Comment: The answer to _"How can I compare 2 objects to see they are equal?"_ depends on whether `{ "price": 14.31, "taxes": 2.00, "total": 16.31 }` and `{ "price": 14.31, "total": 16.31, "taxes": 2.00 }` are equal or different. The given answer  considers these two objects as different.

Comment: @jabaa still confused about the different or equal. They will be 2 separate objects compared together. Not sure if that helps

Comment: Why is the question still open without an accepted answer? What's wrong with the given answer and does the duplicate answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When objects are different:

```
     const priceOne = {
            "price": 14.31,
            "taxes": 2.00,
            "total": 16.31
      }

      const priceTwo = {
            "price": 12.31,
            "taxes": 2.00,
            "total": 16.31
        }

let comparePrice = true

 for (let key in priceOne){
    if(priceOne[key] != priceTwo[key]){
       comparePrice = false
     }`
  }`
```

the variable will be false when objects are the same :

```
const priceOne = {
       "price": 14.31,
       "taxes": 2.00,
       "total": 16.31
 }

const priceTwo = {
      "price": 14.31,
      "taxes": 2.00,
      "total": 16.31
}
```

the result will be true.

I hope I helped

Instead of string or number is array we can easier add extra validation

```
 const priceOne = { a: '0' };

 const priceTwo = { a: [0] };

 let comparePrice = true

for (let key in priceOne) {

if(Array.isArray(priceTwo[key] )){
    if (priceOne[key] != priceTwo[key].toString()) {
    comparePrice = false
  }
}else if(Array.isArray(priceOne[key] )) {
    if (priceOne[key].toString() != priceTwo[key]) {
    comparePrice = false
  }
}
if (priceOne[key] != priceTwo[key]) {
    comparePrice = false
   }
}

console.log(comparePrice);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for `{ a: '0' }` and `{ a: [0] }`: https://jsfiddle.net/0nqaduk7/

Comment: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/tegsq365/ You can of course do better, I add validation for arrays,

Comment: You should add it to your question, not to an external code in a link in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would `JSON.stringify()` and compare that way .. IE:

```
if ( JSON.stringify(priceOne) === JSON.stringify(priceTwo) ){
```

Comment: this doesn't work if the keys are in a different order, also takes a lot of extra memory and time by stringifying

Comment: @Samathingamajig,  Correct .. But in my eyes .. Those objects would not be "equal"  -- They would contain equal "parts" -- But they are not the "same"

Comment: also stringifying doesn't work (throws an error) if there is any referential loops